# Pandas grouping with count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data frame looks like -

```
name        clicked
    a            1
    b            0
    c            0
    c            0
    d            0
    a            1
    a            0
    b            1
    b            0
```

my final data frame looks like -

```
name      no_clicked_1         no_clicked_0
a             2                     0
b             1                     2
c             1                     1
d             0                     1
```

We can do groupby on name for each 1 and 0. Then merge those data frame. Is there any way we can do this thing in pandas.

Comment: `final=pd.crosstab(df['name'],df['clicked'])` and `final.add_prefix(f"no_{m.columns.name}_")`

Comment: @anky_91 - thanks for your quick reply..but getting this error - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crosstab'

Comment: No problem , dataframe has no such attributes, use `pd.crosstab()` as shown above, or follow solution linked in the dupe, both solves your problem

Comment: @anky_91 - i have done ..final=pd.crosstab(df_train['user_offer_merchant'],df_train['rating'])
final.add_prefix(f"no_{m.columns.name}_")...getting error - NameError: name 'm' is not defined

Comment: My bad replace `m` with `final` , also execute them as separate lines

Comment: @anky_91 - this line is not reflecting - final.add_prefix(f"no_{final.columns.name}_")
 and also i think reset_index() is needed otherwise column name is not properly showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204710/discussion-between-anky-91-and-nikita-agarwal).